# Keyset to Set of string

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map<Type, Data>`
We need to convert the keySet of the map to a LinkedHashSet of String.
What is the most efficient way to do it using java 8 stream.

Comment: Did you have tried anything?

Comment: `map.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));`

Comment: @HadiJ that stream op doesn’t convert the keys. When no conversion is required, you can use the even simpler `new LinkedHashSet<>(map.keySet())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
map.keySet().stream().map(Object::toString).collect(toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```